# Scroll ListView To Top On ItemsSource Changed Is Called Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, scrollview

I've got a wpf user control project set up similar (for the most part) to the [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). Basically, I have a headered content control, that houses a tab control. The first tab holds search results and any additional tabs are opened by clicking on an item from the search results to see a more detailed view of the item.

My main problem is that I reuse the search results tab any time someone types in search criteria and runs the search command. The scrollviewer does not scroll to the top when the search results collection is repopulated (if the user had scrolled down the list).

Originally I was repopulating the search result item collection in a way that caused the CollectionChanged event to fire. Then I looked into using an attached property to allow scrolling to the top and it looked as if replacing the entire collection was the way to go (since ItemsControl does not implement the ICollectionNotifyChanged interface).

So I made the change and all seemed well. Running a new search replaced the search results item collection, which fired the attached property and scrolled the listview back to the top. However, I now have a problem that **whenever I move to another tab** to view a detailed view of an item, **it fires the attached property and scrolls the search results on the first tab to the top**. I'm not sure how to address this situation.

```
public static class ScrollToTopBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollToTopProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
            (
                "ScrollToTop",
                typeof (bool),
                typeof (ScrollToTopBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollToTopPropertyChanged)
            );

    public static bool GetScrollToTop(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(ScrollToTopProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrollToTop(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ScrollToTopProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnScrollToTopPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo,
                                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsControl = dpo as ItemsControl;
        if (itemsControl == null) return;

        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dependencyPropertyDescriptor =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof (ItemsControl));
        if (dependencyPropertyDescriptor == null) return;
        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            dependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(itemsControl, ItemsSourceChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            dependencyPropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged(itemsControl, ItemsSourceChanged);
        }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsControl = sender as ItemsControl;
        EventHandler eventHandler = null;
        eventHandler = delegate
            {
                if (itemsControl != null &&
                    itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                {
                    var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<ScrollViewer>(itemsControl);
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToTop();
                    itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= eventHandler;
                }
            };
        if (itemsControl != null) itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += eventHandler;
    }
}
```

I've attached this property to a search results user control like so:

```
<ListView ...some properties left out for brevity...
              DataContext="{StaticResource SearchResultsViewSource}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              behaviours:ScrollToTopBehavior.ScrollToTop="True">
...etc...
```

The search results control is housed inside of another user control that is using a headered content control (I'll provide the details if needed).

Comment: Try to set the `ListView` property `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`. Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev, no go. Still scrolls when I change tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and doesn't resolve your real issue but it will resolve the symptoms.
You can detach the your behavior on `tabControl.Selecting` event,
so when you start or go to the search results tab you attach the behavior/property and when you go to other tabs you detach/unregister the behavior.

should look like this:

```
yourTab.SelecnionChanged+= new TabControlCancelEventHandler(tabControl_Selecting);

void tabControl_SelecnionChange(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var current = (sender as TabControl).SelectedValue;

    //check if current is search tab then
    {
      ScrollToTopBehavior.SetScrollToTop(yourList,true);
    }
    else
    {
      ScrollToTopBehavior.SetScrollToTop(yourList,false);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. At this point I'm willing to use a hack and address the symptoms and get back to fixing this later (famous last words... the hack will probably be around for years hehe).

Comment: Looks like TabContrl.Selecting is not an event in WPF (it is from WinForms). I'll have to use the SelectionChanged event instead.

Comment: Well getting a hold of the list is proving to be difficult. It's view (user control) hooked up via a datatemplate for a different view model. I already want to avoid view code behind if possible and this approach is turning out not to be a quick workaround =\ +1 for the idea though... in some scenarios it would be a quick fix that would work.

Comment: @JasonDown you can try attaching and detaching using trigger based on the selectedIndex property. returning to the real issue : I guess you already tried using snoop to see which events of the tabControl or selector are being fired? and might cause the attached property to fire

Comment: @JasonDown I really dont know when to give up :) here is another idea since getting a hold of a list is a problem you might consider changing the Attached Property to behavior and using System.Windows.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection to detach/attach it.
Disclaimer: I've never used BehaviorCollection

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into them later this week (have to get the rest of the functionality done before going back to fix minor things). If I can manage to fix the issue with either of these suggestions I'll let you know. Thanks!